# Fuzzy matching multiple columns in BigQuery when left-joining

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, fuzzy-comparison

**Example**

```
with
    lhs_table as (
        select 'Nia' as firstName, 'Johnson Jr.' as lastName, 'FEMALE' as gender, 'UNLV' as school, 'Mountain West Conference' as conference union all
        select 'Jana' as firstName, 'Abdullah' as lastName, 'FEMALE' as gender, 'Cincinnati' as school, 'American Athletic Conference' as conference union all
        select 'Kay' as firstName, 'Sieper' as lastName, 'FEMALE' as gender, 'Loyola Maryland' as school, 'Patriot League' as conference union all
        select 'Alessia' as firstName, 'Capley' as lastName, 'FEMALE' as gender, 'Presbyterian' as school, 'Big South Conference' as conference union all
        select 'Aaliyah' as firstName, 'Stanley' as lastName, 'FEMALE' as gender, 'FGCU' as school, 'ASUN Conference' as conference 
    ),

    rhs_table as (
        select 1611707 as playerId, 'Kayla' as firstName, 'Sieper' as lastName, 'Loyola Maryland' as teamMarket, 'Patriot League' as conferenceName union all
        select 1380430 as playerId, 'Jana' as firstName, 'Abdullah' as lastName, 'Cincinnati' as teamMarket, 'American Athletic Conference' as conferenceName union all
        select 1234567 as playerId, 'Mela' as firstName, 'Aravada' as lastName, 'Cincinnati' as teamMarket, 'American Athletic Conference' as conferenceName union all
        select 1354105 as playerId, 'Aaliyah' as firstName, 'Stanley' as lastName, 'FGCU' as teamMarket, 'ASUN Conference' as conferenceName union all
        select 1138439 as playerId, 'Aaliyah' as firstName, 'Stanley' as lastName, 'Emory' as teamMarket, 'ASUN Conference' as conferenceName union all
        select 996101 as playerId, 'Nia' as firstName, 'Johnson' as lastName, 'Emmanuel (GA)' as teamMarket, 'Conference Carolinas' as conferenceName union all
        select 977605 as playerId, 'Nia' as firstName, 'Johnson' as lastName, 'UNLV' as teamMarket, 'Mountain West Conference' as conferenceName union all
        select 1329967 as playerId, 'Alessia' as firstName, 'Capley' as lastName, 'Presbyterian' as teamMarket, 'Big South Conference' as conferenceName union all
        select 995234 as playerId, 'Nia' as firstName, 'Johnson' as lastName, 'Delta St.' as teamMarket, 'Gulf South Conference' as conferenceName union all
        select 4567890 as playerId, 'Britney' as firstName, 'Capley' as lastName, 'Presbyterian' as teamMarket, 'Big South Conference' as conferenceName
    )

select 
    b.playerId
    ,a.*
from lhs_table as a 
left join rhs_table as b
    on a.firstName = b.firstName
    and a.lastName = b.lastName
    and a.school = b.teamMarket
    and a.conference = b.conferenceName
```

[image]

We are looking to join `rhs_table` onto `lhs_table` for the playerIds. Every person in `lhs_table` has a corresponding row in `rhs_table`, however the joins are not so simple:

- For Nia Johnson Jr., `Jr.` is missing in `rhs_table`
- For Kay Sieper, her full name `Kayla` is used in `rhs_table`
- We want to ignore (ie not left join) RHS players on the wrong team (Nia on Emmanuel, Aaliyah on Emory).

Because of these mismatches, we need to `fuzzy match` instead. We have tried replacing `on a.firstName = b.firstName` with `on a.firstName like b.firstName`. Note that the conferences are the 1 column that do match exactly between tables, and also if it helps we can manually ensure that the teams match, although it would take some time. The important part is handling names not spelt the same.

The 5 correct playerIds, in order, are `977605, 1380430, 1611707, 1329967, 1354105`. Can we somehow fuzzy match to get these playerIds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select 
  array_agg(b.playerId order by d limit 1) playerId,
  any_value(a).*
from (
  select 
    `bqutil.fn.levenshtein`(a.firstName, b.firstName) / greatest(length(a.firstName), length(b.firstName)) + 
    `bqutil.fn.levenshtein`(a.lastName, b.lastName) / greatest(length(a.lastName), length(b.lastName)) + 
    `bqutil.fn.levenshtein`(a.school, b.teamMarket) / greatest(length(a.school), length(b.teamMarket)) + 
    `bqutil.fn.levenshtein`(a.conference, b.conferenceName) / greatest(length(a.conference), length(b.conferenceName)) d,
    a, b
  from lhs_table as a 
  cross join rhs_table as b
)
group by to_json_string(a)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

You can play/experiment with variation of above, like below as an example

```
select 
  array_agg(b.playerId order by d limit 1) playerId,
  any_value(a).*
from (
  select 
    `bqutil.fn.levenshtein`(format('%t', a), format('%t', b)) d,
    a, b
  from lhs_table as a 
  cross join rhs_table as b
)
group by to_json_string(a)
```

Comment: if our actual `lhs_table` and `rhs_table` had ~100K rows each rather than 5-10, would that be computationally problematic with the `cross join`?

Comment: If you have some (at least one) column that you know will have exact match - you can use join on such column(s)

Comment: `cross join with_names_added as b on a.school = b.teamMarket and a.conference = b.conferenceName` - something like this doesn't work. Assuming these columns were exact matches, how could I join on those columns while still using cross join?

Comment: I've edited the question such that the schools and conferences match

Comment: Replace cross join with just join

Comment: Function not found: `bqutil.fn.levenshtein` - is there a process to installing bqutil?

Comment: check out https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/tree/master/udfs/community

Comment: I think my issue with the `function not found` is that the processing location for my bigquery is us-west2. when the processing zone is US, the function runs just fine.

Comment: per https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/blob/master/udfs/README.md, it says that `ll UDFs within this repository are available under the bqutil project on publicly shared datasets. Queries can then reference the shared UDFs via bqutil.<dataset>.<function>().` I wonder if this means I cannot use the bqutil functions with tables in my own non-public dataset?

Comment: I spun this convo into its own question which is more clearly defined - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70935769/cannot-use-bigquery-udf-bqutil-in-processing-location-us-west-2