# Cannot use bigquery udf (bqutil) in processing location: us-west-2

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

We are trying to use these in us-west2 - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/tree/master/udfs/community.

**this first query processes just fine, in US**
[image]

**this second query wont run**
[image]

Our dataset `models` is in us West 2. It seems all queries from the 2nd query editor are then processed in us-west 2 where, it seems `bqutil` does not exist? How can we find the function `bqutil.fn.levenshtein` when processing in us-west2 (where our datasets all exist)?

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/52263170/5221944 for levenshtein UDF implementation. also just search for "levenshtein " here on SO to see many more options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the levenshtein UDF in your BigQuery table, you need to create a UDF in the location where your dataset resides.

You can refer to the below UDF and the screenshot where the data resides in **us-west2** location.

**UDF :**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
`stackdemo.fn_LevenshteinDistance`(in_a STRING, in_b STRING) RETURNS INT64 LANGUAGE js AS R"""

var a = in_a.toLowerCase();
var b = in_b.toLowerCase();
 if(a.length == 0) return b.length;
if(b.length == 0) return a.length;
var matrix = [];
// increment along the first column of each row
var i;
for(i = 0; i <= b.length; i++){
 matrix[i] = [i];
}
// increment each column in the first row
var j;
for(j = 0; j <= a.length; j++){
 matrix[0][j] = j;
}
// Fill in the rest of the matrix
for(i = 1; i <= b.length; i++){
 for(j = 1; j <= a.length; j++){
   if(b.charAt(i-1) == a.charAt(j-1)){
     matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j-1];
   } else {
     matrix[i][j] =
       Math.min(matrix[i-1][j-1] + 1, // substitution
       Math.min(matrix[i][j-1] + 1, // insertion
       matrix[i-1][j] + 1)); // deletion
   }
 }
}
return matrix[b.length][a.length];
""";
```

**Query :**

```
SELECT
 source,
 target,
 `stackdemo.fn_LevenshteinDistance`(source, target) distance,
FROM UNNEST([
 STRUCT('analyze' AS source, 'analyse' AS target),
 STRUCT('opossum', 'possum'),
 STRUCT('potatoe', 'potatoe'),
 STRUCT('while', 'whilst'),
 STRUCT('aluminum', 'alumininium'),
 STRUCT('Connecticut', 'CT')
]);
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: this makes sense, thanks! did you create this UDF yourself, or find it online somewhere? I could not find this in the repo I shared.

Comment: also, what is the function scripting syntax for the UDF? is this javascript?

Comment: this is working, this is fantastic, appreciate it

Comment: Hi @Canovice, I took the code reference from the thread link shared by Mikhail Berlyant and yes the UDF is written in javascript.

Comment: Glad to help you @Canovice